# Автоматический Regex'er со строки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте. У меня есть две строки:

1) Строка-идеал (хранится в виде: "arg1 arg2 [blabla] something [something2] arg100500"
2) Входная строка (строка, которую ввел пользователь)

В `Set<String>` я храню доступные "строки-идеалы". Из всех мне нужно подобрать именно ту, у которой все **фиксированые** аргументы подходят под входную строку. Пример:

Входная строка=`arg20 arg21 blakdlalkla blabla arg22`; паттерны: `arg100500 arg21 [somethindanda] [blabla] arg22` и `arg20 arg21 [somethindanda312] [blabl33a] arg22`. Должна выбратся первый паттерн, потому что все обычные аргументы (которые не в "[ ]") совпадают. Сделать с минимальными затратами ресурсов и, желательно, используя Regex, или как быстрее.

Знаю, что много прошу - но я не знаю что и как. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

1. Заменяете в строках идеалах последовательности вида `[abc]` на `.*`;
2. Полученные регулярные выражения проверяете на соответствие вашей строке;
3. Если подходит, значит соответствующая строка-идеал подходит.